# Two soundpool volume controls

Tags: android, volume, soundpool

I'm making a white noise app, I would like to control the volume for each sound independently.  Is this possible?

Here is my onCreate at the moment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mySound = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    whiteNoiseId = mySound.load(this, R.raw.whitenoise, 1);
    rainId = mySound.load(this, R.raw.rain, 1);


    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    SeekBar noiseVolumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.noiseSeekBar);
    noiseVolumeControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    noiseVolumeControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    SeekBar rainVolumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rainSeekBar);
    rainVolumeControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    rainVolumeControl.setProgress(curVolume);

    noiseVolumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    rainVolumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
```

This controls just the main volume, I'd like to be able to lower one and raise the other.

Thanks!

Comment: It should work with the method `SoundPool.setVolume()`. By passing the different streamId, it should take different effect on both sounds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should work with `SoundPool.setVolume(int id,float leftVol,float rightVol);` method. I have not tried it, but I guess it must be:

```
mySound.setVolume(whiteNoiseId,0.2,0.2);

mySoundPool.setVolume(rainId,0.8,0.8);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although when I stop and start the sound again, it looses control with the seekbar.  New question being posted now!